# Grep complete name including dot in pattern

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to grep the complete word with dot.

Like I have file `test.txt`

Data in file:

```
Abc  ABC.xyz abc ABC.xyz 
Def  DEF.mno def DEF.mno
```

When I am using `grep -o` I am getting below output

```
grep -o "\w*ABC\w*" test.txt
```

Output : `ABC`

I want complete word `ABC.xyz`

Comment: have you tried `ABC\.xyz`?

Comment: Why are you using `grep -o` when you want the whole line?  Why not just `grep ABC test.txt`?

Comment: grep -o is still a good way of getting just the matching portion without the whole line. Is there other data on each line that you don't want? If not, omit the -o option.

Comment: Apologies!.....I have update the data in file

Comment: Right, so: grep -o 'ABC.xyz' test.txt should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\w` means "word characters" (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and `.` isn't ever a part of a word:

```
 $ echo . | grep '\w'
 $
```

You could just search for non-whitespace:

```
$ echo ABC.xyz | grep '\S*ABC\S*'
ABC.xyz
```

Note that `\S` might not be universally understood. If it doesn't work in your implementation, use `grep -E` instead.

Comment: Did you try the `[^\b]` solution on the given input? Probably not what the OP wanted. The `\S` solution is likely the desired one.

Comment: @Philippos d'oh! Ouch, you're quite right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/ABC/ { print $NF }' test.txt
```

This would use `awk` to match the string `ABC` against the contents of each line.  If a line matches, the last whitespace-delimited word is outputted.

If you want to match against the first field on the line, use `$1 ~ /Abc/` rather than `/ABC/`.  If you want to do a string comparison with the first field, use `$1 == "Abc"`.

To pass the string that you compare against on the command line, use e.g.

```
awk -v str="Abc" '$1 == str { print $NF }' test.txt
```

To pass a pattern that you compare against on the command line, use e.g.

```
awk -v pat="ABC" '$1 ~ pat { print $NF }' test.txt
```

Change `$1` to `$0` to compare against the whole line.

---

Using your own approach with `grep`, and assuming you don't know the filename suffix (if that's what it is), using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -o '\<ABC\.\w*\>' test.txt
```

The `\<` matches the start of a word while `\>` matches at the end.

This would give you *two* `ABC.txt` though, as it occurs twice on the first line.

With a non-GNU implementation of `grep` you would use `[_[:alnum:]]` in place of `\w` (this would work in GNU `grep` too).

Comment: Actually what I was trying to do is that I have to find the word with some pattern. And it is not necessary that word has "." in it but it is possible. So I want to grep the word till next blank space (with dot in result, if present)

Comment: @Arnav Added something that will compare a pattern against the first word on the line. Change `$1` to `$0` to compare against the whole line, or to some other column number to compare against that column.